# How to get the icon of a UWP app in C++/Rust?

Tags: c++, windows, rust, uwp, icons

I'm looking to get the (main) icon of a UWP/Windows store app in C++ or Rust. (Using Windows APIs)

I have all these IDs available (with Slack for example):

```
System.AppUserModel.ID
91750D7E.Slack_8she8kybcnzg4!Slack

System.AppUserModel.PackageFamilyName
91750D7E.Slack_8she8kybcnzg4

System.AppUserModel.PackageFullName
91750D7E.Slack_4.33.73.0_x64__8she8kybcnzg4

System.AppUserModel.TileUniqueId
{AFFCE86E-C26B-4855-83E5-CDAB2333488B}
```

I just want to retrieve a HICON, HBITMAP, png path, whatever. (The endgoal being to convert it in base64)

**Can someone point me on the right direction? Maybe a I missed a windows function to do that?**

I already tried all these functions from Windows API but none of them seems to work for this usecase:

- `ExtractIconExW`
- `ExtractAssociatedIconW`
- `SHCreateItemFromParsingName` then `GetImage` on `IShellItemImageFactory`
- `SHGetFileInfoW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to get the logo URI, here's the code in Rust:

```rust
let app_full_name = r"Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_11.2210.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe";

let package_manager = PackageManager::new().unwrap();
let package = package_manager.FindPackageByPackageFullName(&HSTRING::from(app_full_name));
let logoUri = package.unwrap().Logo().unwrap().AbsoluteUri();

println!("{:?}", logoUri);
// Ok("file:///C:/Program%20Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_11.2210.0.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe/Assets/CalculatorStoreLogo.scale-100.png")
```

But it requires admin privilege, which is a bit too much for just getting a file path...

So if anyone has a solution that doesn't require admin privilege, that would be awesome!

---

EDIT: ok, apparently, I just needed to use the `FindPackageByUserSecurityIdPackageFullName` method instead, with an empty SID:

```rust
let package_manager = PackageManager::new().unwrap();
let package = package_manager.FindPackageByUserSecurityIdPackageFullName(&HSTRING::from(""), &HSTRING::from(app_full_name));
let logoUri = package.unwrap().Logo().unwrap().AbsoluteUri();
```

Comment: Glad you have a workaround, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I must wait 48h after posting to accept my own answer, I'll have to wait 20h more before being able to mark it as accepted - Stackoverflow rules...

Comment: Still requires admin privilege to access the icon folder. I guess Microsoft just went paranoid about security.